# How to build Google protobuf without using iostreams?

Tags: c++, serialization, iostream, protocol-buffers

The title sums it up. The project I am currently working on doesn't use iostreams. And we are using STLport. We would like to use the google protobuf library for message serialization and deserialization over ethernet. Has anyone built protobuf without using iostreams?

Comment: I don't mean to be critical, but why would you want to _avoid_ using iostreams?

Comment: My last project doubled in size when I added IOstreams (to 150 KB, I admit ;) )

Comment: @Mooing-Duck: One of the hardware platforms is built using eVC++ and STLport didn't build properly with IOStreams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking about interacting with protobufs without using iostreams? Are actually building without the types visible. This is what you can do to interact with them without the types:

Yes using protobufs without IOStreams is very possible. All protocol buffers messages support methods such as

- ParseFromArray
- ParasePartialFromArray
- ParseFromString
- ParsePartialFromString

that allow you to implemented everything using your own buffers.

To build without the types you could in theory give it stubs to satisfy the requirements and get it to compile since you won't need them if you use the above interface.